# Ubuntu 18.04 does not work on a MacBook

Tags: macbook

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 working very well on a MacBook (2010, CPE Intel Core Duo 2.4 GHz, graphic NVIDIA GeoForce 320 M), along MacOS Sierra.
It is just a second computer I use, I thought I could explore the new version before upgrading my main computer.

1. I tried to upgrade to 18.04 but Ubuntu would hang on errors on boot.
2. So I reinstalled 16.04
3. Then I tested 18.04 with an USB installation key - wich I should have done first. I get the same kind of errors. This time it loads until it even displays the background of the desktop, then displays errors in text mode and hangs.

Example of error messages of to-day (were different yesterday):

```
Could'nt get size: 0x8000000000...0e
nouveau 0000:02:00,0: bus: MMI0 write of 0000807f FAULT at 100c18
nouveau 0000:02:00,0: bus: MMI0 write of 0000807f FAULT at 100c1c
```

It is not a big deal as I do not have to upgrade now.

I tested Lubuntu 18.04 from a USB key. It seems to work.

Comment: Summary: did you tested it with *Ubuntu* 18.04, and it didn't work? But, you can only boot from USB with *Lubuntu*?